# post request to change permissions for a file in google drive is failing

Tags: python, google-drive-api

Im using python requests library to make google a drive api request to change permissions of a file, in this case the owner.

Here is what my code looks like

```
fileId = "123abcEfJl-mNooP45Kl6u" #fake file id
url = https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/%s/permissions' % fileId
payload = {"role":"owner", "type":"user", "value":"<some_user>@gmail.com"}
headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer %s'%access_token, 'Content-Type':'application/json'}
permResponse = requests.post(url, data=payload, headers=headers)
print permResponse.text
```

When I run this, I get the following response:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "parseError",
    "message": "Parse Error"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Parse Error"
 }
}
```

I've been following the google docs api for this and have not been able to figure out what im doing incorrectly.
https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/permissions/insert

Even their Try It! section is broken because there isn't an option to add the required 'value' field.

What am I doing incorrectly? Is anyone else running into these issues?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the urllib.request module, and It works fine.  This is my code:

```
key = "?key=" + MY_API_KEY
url_destino = ("https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/%s/permissions" % source_id)+ key
values = "{"role":"owner", "type":"user", "value":"<some_user>@gmail.com"}"
data = values.encode('utf-8')
request = urllib.request.Request(url_destino, data, method='POST')
request.add_header("Authorization", "Bearer " + token)
request.add_header("Content-Length", len(data))
request.add_header("Content-Type", "application/json")
print(request.header_items())    # for debugging purpouse
f = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
print(f.read())
```

I've thought to replace the urllib.request by [Requests module](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) (it's more clean to work with) in my little library but, now works.

Because I use Python 3 I can't use the google-api-python-client.

Comment: @arizqi Any idea what this error means?  I'm getting the same error but in a different language, and this is the only reference I have seen to "parse error" in this request